# Copy fro Sheet A to paste in Sheet B's last row google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm just trying to learn javascript and google apps script for 2-3 weeks.

I'm copying the whole range from 11 to 200 from Sheet A.
Then I need to paste this copied data in Sheet B's last row.

I made a code here which has an error.

```
   function CopyandPasteToB() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mysheet = ss.getSheetByName('B')
  
  //copy data from origin sheet
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('A'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('11:100').activate();
  
  // Last non-empty row
  var rlast = mysheet.getLastRow();
  Logger.log("Last row = " + rlast);
 
  // Insert into last row in OP
  mysheet.insertRows(rlast+1);
  var r = rlast+1;
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'WP1\'!11:100').copyTo(mysheet.getLastRow() +1);
};
```

I get an error  of
Exception: The parameters (number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.copyTo.

Aside from the error that I got, do you think my code can be improved and am I in the right direction to achieve my goal?

SO I want to ask how do I go about this to work?

Thank you very much.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The parameter provided to [copyTo(range)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range)) should be a [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#), not a number. That's the reason for your issue.
- There's no need to `activate` Sheets and Ranges in order to work on them, so your code could be simplified.

#### Code snippet:

```
function CopyandPasteToB() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mysheet = ss.getSheetByName('B');
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('A');
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange("11:100");
  var rlast = mysheet.getLastRow();
  if (rlast === mysheet.getMaxRows()) mysheet.insertRowsAfter(rlast, 1); // Avoid error if last row with content is last row of the sheet
  var destRange = mysheet.getRange(rlast + 1, 1);
  sourceRange.copyTo(destRange);
};
```

Comment: thank you, just came back from a long holiday. It worked :D have a wonderful day.